# Displaying an image of a file from input

Tags: reactjs, input-type-file

I am trying to show an image of a file that was selected from input without sending data to the server.

Wanted to do it with `URL.createObjectUrl`.

```
const onImageChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
          this.setState({
            image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
          });
        }
       }
```

```
<input type="file" 
      onChange={onImageChange} 
      className="filetype" 
      id="group_image"/>
```

And then pass an image inside

```
<img 
      id="target" 
      src={this.state.image}/>
```

But i get **undefined has no properties** with this code. So does anyone know how to do it?

EDIT: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sun-61uui?file=/src/App.js

Full code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Addfile = () => {
const onImageChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
          this.setState({
            image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
          });
        }
       }

    return (
        <div>
      <input type="file" 
      onChange={onImageChange} 
      className="filetype" 
      id="group_image"/>
      
      <img 
      id="target" 
      src={this.state.image}/> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Addfile
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan of course

Comment: You're going to have to show more code in your post, too, though, because just showing the `<input>` code without showing whether this is a function, or a component class, etc. isn't super useful. (links to external sites are fine, but only _in addition_ to showing [mcve] code in your post. Remember: future visitors need to benefit, too, and external links can turn into 404s unexpectedly fast)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a functional component. There is not `this.state`, isn't it?

You should use `useState`. I updated the codesandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-noether-3tz4f?file=/src/App.js